# How to set Win10 Guest account to a default input method?

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, input-languages

I have my Guest account enabled on Windows 10 (English version).

I type Chinese using a specific Chinese input lanuage method,
I stalled it and have also set it as the ONLY input method.
But the Guest account still uses "pure" English input method.....

I have also tried to install a Chinese Language Interface(Pack),
Guest account still uses "pure" English input method.....

I tried to restart after change the settings。
I tried to delete the Profile too for Guest account.

Nothing happens...

How could I get the Guest account to run the Chinese Input?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 no longer allows you to create a Guest account. That feature was deprecated and is gone. It shows up as a disable account but does not work / cannot be used.

So you need to create a Standard Account of your own for guests to use.  You can call it MyComputerGuest or some such thing.

But it is for you to do because Windows 10 no longer provides the feature.

[Microsoft removed Guest Account](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/151705/guest-account-and-its-privileges-in-windows-10.html)

> Do note however that Windows 10 no longer offers a Guest account to
> share your PC, but you can create a restricted account to emulate that
> kind of functionality

Here is a Microsoft Article on creating an account

[Guest Account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-a-local-user-or-administrator-account-in-windows-10-20de74e0-ac7f-3502-a866-32915af2a34d#:%7E:text=Select%20Start%20%3E%20Settings%20%3E%20Accounts%20and,user%20without%20a%20Microsoft%20account.)

> Select Start  > Settings  > Accounts  and then select Family & other
> users. (In some versions of Windows you'll see Other users.)
>
> Select Add someone else to this PC.
>
> Select I don't have this person's sign-in information, and on the next
> page, select Add a user without a Microsoft account.
>
> Enter a user name, password, or password hint—or choose security
> questions—and then select Next.

Comment: It is still here in Win10 version 21H1.

Comment: The account is disabled in Windows 10 (any recent version) and no longer functions as Guest.

Comment: I know how to active it and I already did. I was seeking to enable the Input method.....

Comment: You cannot enable it by the input method - I posted that as well

Comment: @CasperYC - There are countless questions here at Super User, that explains that even if you enable it, the Guest account cannot be used (this is also supported by hundreds of articles).  Windows doesn’t even offer a way to delete built-in accounts.  The user interface is handle primarily through language packs but also through the legacy control panel when setting the locale.  Provide some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Your guest account was probably created before you changed the input method
and now cannot change its own input method because of lack of permissions.

I suggest to disable it and create a replacement account with another name.
The method is described in the article
[How to create a guest account on your Windows 10 computer in 6 steps](https://www.businessinsider.fr/us/how-to-create-a-guest-account-on-windows-10),
which I summarize here:

- Run the Command Prompt (CMD) as administrator
- Create: `net user Friend /add /active:yes`
- No password: `net user Friend *`
- Login as Friend and ensure that it uses the correct input method,
  change if required
- Return to your login and run again the Command Prompt (CMD) as administrator
- Remove Friend from the Users group: `net localgroup users Friend /delete`
- Add to the Guests group: `net localgroup guests Friend /add`
- Done.